# ASP.NET Website Projec type not picking up correct configuration

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, buildconfiguration

I have an ASP.NET Website 4.5 (not Web Application that has .csproj) and using Visual Studio 2013.

I have created different build configuration: Debug, QA and Stage.

I have set the Build configuration to QA.
[image]

All my projects in the solution are built as QA but just this site will build as Debug.

### Build Summary

00:00.356 - Success - **Debug Any CPU** - http://localhost:63864

00:00.001 - Success - QA    Any CPU - ....\Project1\Project1.csproj

00:00.001 - Success - QA    Any CPU - ....\Project2\Project2.csproj

00:00.001 - Success - QA    Any CPU - ....\Project3\Project3.csproj

Because of this, site is picking up Debug web.config instead of QA transforms.

Any idea what am I missing here?

Comment: try visiting the Configuration Manager and see if for that project the configuration is set to debug/release or QA.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention....the configurations is not showing up in there as well....